# app is not showing any layout

Tags: android, firebase, layout

I am working on this project since months, but at the time of launching I am not getting any kind of elements in my main layout.

Here is the screenshot https://www.dropbox.com/s/99d2lr6ffo4klxc/Screenshot_20180413-064226.png?dl=0

Here is my  build gradle file.

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()

    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    mavenCentral()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Here is my app gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.cofoz.cofoz"
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 2
    versionName "1.1"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

}
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
    preDexLibraries true

    jumboMode true
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
        // Disables PNG crunching for the release build type.
        crunchPngs false

    }
}

sourceSets { main { assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 
'src/main/assets/'] } }
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:27.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:27.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-dynamic-animation:27.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:palette-v7:27.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint- 
layout:1.0.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
core:3.0.1'

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'


implementation 'com.github.andremion:counterfab:1.0.1'

implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.2.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'


//implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'

implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:3.2.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'

// Required only if Facebook login support is required
//implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.27.0'

implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0'
//implementation 'com.github.DanielMartinus:Stepper-Touch:0.6'
//implementation 'com.stone.vega.library:VegaLayoutManager:1.0.6'

implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'

implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
//implementation'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:11.8.0'

implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.2.5'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0'

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0'


//implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'

implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.2.0'

//implementation 'com.github.GrenderG:Toasty:1.2.8'
implementation 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:0.4@aar'
implementation 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.5.0'
//implementation 'com.github.ganfra:material-spinner:2.0.0'
//implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:11.8.0'
//implementation 'com.github.thomper:sweet-alert-dialog:v1.4.0'
// Shimmer
implementation 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.1.0@aar'

implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:4.2.0'

implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.6.0'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

My mainactivity.java goes like this.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        Window window = getWindow();

// clear FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS flag:
        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);

// add FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS flag to the window
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);

// finally change the color
        window.setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.colorPrimary));
    }

    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    LinearLayout bottomsheetLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet);

    counterFab = (CounterFab) findViewById(R.id.counter_fab);
    bottomDishName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dishNameBottom);
    dishBottomPrice = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dishBottomPrice);
    txtIngredients = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtIngredients);
    counterFab.setTranslationY(counterFab.getHeight() + 16);
    floatingLay = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.floatingLay);
    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);


    headerName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.headerName);
    mLogout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.logout);


    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    user_id = mUser.getUid();


    mFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

    mDatabaseUser = mFirestore.collection("Users").document(user_id);


    bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomsheetLayout);

    bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            counterFab.animate().translationY(0).setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator(2)).start();
        }
    }, 100);
    cardLoading = (CardLoading) getApplicationContext();


    counterFab.setCount(cardLoading.getFabCount());
    //gps = new GPSTracker(MainActivity.this);
    //Toast.makeText(this, "Location:"+Double.toString(gps.getLatitude()) + Double.toString(gps.getLongitude()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    //Toast.makeText(this, "FabCount:"+Integer.toString(cardLoading.getFabCount()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    /*mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Location location) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Location:" + Double.toString(location.getLatitude()) + "," + Double.toString(location.getLongitude()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });*/




    //Toast.makeText(this, userName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //Toast.makeText(this, userEmail, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    /*FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });*/

    //locationStr = getIntent().getStringExtra("Location");





    sp = getSharedPreferences("profile_data", MODE_PRIVATE);
    spCart = getSharedPreferences("Cart_details", MODE_PRIVATE);

    //String name = sp.getString("Name", "Your Name");

    //String cartCount = spCart.getString("CartCount", "0");
    //Toast.makeText(this, cartCount, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //Integer c = Integer.valueOf(cartCount);
    //counterFab.setCount(c);





    View header=navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
    View view=navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.nav_header_main);
    headerName = (TextView)header.findViewById(R.id.headerName);
    String userName = getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
   mDatabaseUser.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
       @Override
       public void onEvent(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
           Users users = documentSnapshot.toObject(Users.class);
           headerName.setText(users.getName());
       }
   });
    //Toast.makeText(this, userName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //headerName.setText(userName);





    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    mViewPager.beginFakeDrag();

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);


    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    mLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mAuth.signOut();
            Intent logoutIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, WelcomeActivity.class);
            startActivity(logoutIntent);
        }
    });


}



@Override
public void onResume()
{  // After a pause OR at startup
    super.onResume();
    //Refresh your stuff here
    counterFab.setCount(cardLoading.getFabCount());
    //Toast.makeText(this, "FabCount:"+Integer.toString(cardLoading.getFabCount()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}





@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.

    Fragment fragment = null;

    int id = item.getItemId();

    switch (id){
        case R.id.nav_profile:

            Intent profileIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Profile.class);
            startActivity(profileIntent);
            break;
        case R.id.nav_orders:
            Intent ordersIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Orders.class);
            startActivity(ordersIntent);
            break;

    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.content, fragment);
        ft.commit();
    }


    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onPointerCaptureChanged(boolean hasCapture) {

}

class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                OrderNow tabOrdernow = new OrderNow();
                return tabOrdernow;
            case 1:
                MealPlan tabMealPlan = new MealPlan();
                return tabMealPlan;


            default:
                return null;

        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "Order Now";
            case 1:
                return "Meal Plan";

        }
        return null;
    }
}



}
```

And Here is my mainactivity.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/logout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:padding="5dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_power_settings_new_black_24dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Log Out"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

Here is my app_bar_main file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/floatingLay"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white"
tools:context="com.cofoz.cofoz.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="69dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:contentDescription="logo"
            android:src="@mipmap/white_text_cofoz" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>



    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:tabGravity="center"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:tabPadding="10dp"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:tabTextColor="@android:color/black" />


</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

<include
    layout="@layout/bottom_sheet"
    />

<com.andremion.counterfab.CounterFab
    android:id="@+id/counter_fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    app:elevation="11dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_shopping_cart_black_24dp" />
```

Comment: Show the `app_bar_main` .And check the layout.

Comment: What are you expecting to see there? It looks like there's at least a `FloatingActionButton` being shown, so it's loading something.

Comment: Does the drawer comes out if you swipe right from left border?

Comment: app_bar_main added to question

Comment: @Android_K.Doe yes sir, the drawer comes out when i swipe right but I am not able to click on any of its element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in your MainActivity

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Then i suggest remove the child on your `navigationView` and add the logout in your `activity_main_drawer`

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
android:id="@+id/nav_view"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="start"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
app:itemIconTint="@color/colorPrimary"
app:itemTextColor="@color/colorPrimary"
app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" /> //This should end here

//activity drawer menu
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:showIn="navigation_view">

<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/logout"
        android:icon="@drawable/logout_icon"
        android:title="Logout" />
</group>
```

Then to handle click event implement `OnNavigationItemSelectedListener` in your mainActivity

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.logout) {
        //Do something
    } 

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

Hope this helps

EDIT:

If you really want to add custom view in your `navigationView`, you need to create an instance of that view then add an onclicklistener

Comment: My updated MainActivity.java is edited in question, still I m not able see any elements in my layout.